# Is it possible to make satellite imagery viewable through a marker?

Tags: vector, mapbox, markers, satellite

I am working on the project using Mapbox.js and jQuery and the client has asked for something that I'm not sure is possible.

A screenshot of what I currently have is below. The client wants the circular markers to appear on a vector base map (as they currently do), but inside of the vector markers, they want satellite imagery to be shown (like a mask).

[image: circular markers]

Is this even possible? If so, how would I go about doing this? I tried loading both tile sets at the same time, but I haven't been able to get that working. Currently the circles are being generated as markers, but based on [Chris W.](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/28067/chris-w)'s comment, it seems like I might be able to make these markers into masks?

Comment: I don't know the specifics of what software and services you're using (might want to **edit** your question to expand the details), but if it's possible in whatever context that is, the first solution that comes to mind is using your circles (assuming they're polygons and not just markers) as a mask over/for the imagery layer.

Comment: Surely and extremely interesting question, and I would love to see this implemented. Although I doubt that it would be easy, if possible at all. I saw an example that used some kind of magnifying glass lately. Although not the same thing you mighty still want to have a look at it as parts of it could be useful to you as well. Maybe it was even implemented with Mapbox. I am not sure, but I will try to find it tomorrow.

Comment: PS: would you be providing the tiles or would they be served from somewhere else (i.e. Google etc.)?

Comment: The tiles would be served by Mapbox. It would be their [vector tiles](https://www.mapbox.com/developers/vector-tiles/) and [raster tiles](https://www.mapbox.com/blog/one-step-raster-imagery-mapboxcom/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here an example of the 'magnifying glass' I was referring to in the comments last night. It is actually known as [zoom lens](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/zoom-lens/), and I just realized it does much more than zooming, but it can also display a different map, which is exactly what you are looking for, right?

[image]

I am really amazed that this works, and luckily for you it has all been done with Mapbox, so it might be easy for you to get it to work the way your client wants it to. I guess you would have to:
- dig into the code and see how to get rid of the zooming effect
- change the basemap to satellite

Comment: I've found this idea before, but the client wants this to happen on load as opposed to on mouse movement.

Comment: Oh, so the app loads and then a certain number of *fixed* circles will appear in which the imagery is shown?

Comment: Yep! The markers are the fixed circles in this case. I just need to figure out how to take the zoom lens idea and make it on load of the circle markers, apply this zoom lens effect.

Comment: Gotcha now, I missed that before. I am not familiar with the source code, but it should be doable to manipulate the lens so you have it show up multiple times, not moveable, and not zoomed in. If I find some time during the next days I will look into it. Would surely be cool to see that implemented!